# Why do I need extra parentheses for conditional modifier?

Tags: ruby

When I am using a conditional modifier within the argument position of a method, I need an extra pair of parentheses (if the parentheses for the argument are not omitted):

```
def foo bar; end
foo(:baz if true) # => Error
foo(:baz if false) # => Error
foo (:baz if true) # => Error
foo (:baz if false) # => Error
foo((:baz if true)) # => No Error
foo((:baz if false)) # => No Error
```

Why do I need this extra pair of parentheses? Is it dissolving ambiguity?

Answer (score 2):

That’s a matter of operator precedence in Ruby. Consider an example:

```
> [1 if true]
# SyntaxError: unexpected modifier_if, expecting ']'
# [1 if true]
     ^
> [(1 if true)]
# => [
#   [0] 1
# ]
```

Here Ruby wants to evaluate square brackets first. Only when a result is yielded, she will apply the conditional if. Adding round brackets to internal expression resolves an issue and we likely expect the round brackets in function call are to be sufficient as well.

But wait… Ruby uses parentheses in function call to denote the parameter list. Exactly as spaces. And the parameter list is being evaluated **before** any endeavor to even take a look at postfix conditionals. Hence the parameter list became `:baz if true`, while spaces are not permitted in parameter names (there is no idea of conditionals at this stage.)

Adding second pair of parentheses turns a parameter list into one parameter, included within round brackets.

Comment: It's not matter of operator precedence, cause in example: `[1+2]` `+` operation has lower priority (like if_modifier) but this expression evaluates without errors

Comment: I never understood why it’s agreed to consider `[]` of higher priority than arithmetics, but postfix-if is definitely of lowest priority all around.

Comment: Yeah, postfix_if has lowest priority. So, I think, that matter was in space separated parameters list (as you picked)

Answer (score 0):

In some places you can`t use expressions with if_modifier in explicit form - you must evaluate it by use parentheses.

Like your example with function call, you can`t use explicit if_modifier in hash initialization, so code:

```
  a = {'aa' => 1 if true}
```

causes a syntax error, so you also must enclose it to parenthases:

```
  a = {'aa' => (1 if true)}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are expecting a parameter not a conditions, that's why when you write the additional parentheses you have no an error because it return nil or symbol

Comment: In method invocation you are expecting not a parameter, but a expression (`1 if true` - also is expression), so there aren`t so obviously