# Error when no space between method and parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What causes the error below? I expect them both to return 2.

[The Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#parens-no-spaces) encourages no space between method name and parenthesis and accordingly [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_lint.html#lintparenthesesasgroupedexpression) alerts with (safely auto-correctable) Lint/ParenthesesAsGroupedExpression when there is a space. But aligning with the Style Guide and having no space causes an actual error.

```
Integer.sqrt (4 if true) # 2

Integer.sqrt(4 if true) # syntax error, unexpected `if' modifier, expecting ')'
```

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036166/why-do-i-need-extra-parentheses-for-conditional-modifier) 10 years ago which explores similar issues with a top-rated answer (2 votes) that was not accepted by the OP and I find unclear and hard to follow. The response to this question appears far clearer and more comprehensive. This question also references a nuance with Rubocop to be explored further.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, i.e. what’s the purpose of that `if` and what’s the expected result when it evaluates to false?

Comment: The first one works, because if you put space between, it accepts it as a parameter like this: `Integer.sqrt 4`, if you put brackets it is same as: `Integer.sqrt((4 if true))`.

Comment: `Integer.sqrt(nil)` doesn’t make much sense though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exhaustive explanation is quite complex, and requires digging into the [Ruby BNF grammar](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Eregan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf), but the simple(r) explanation requires understanding two things:

1. If you do NOT use the form `function(args)` (without space and with parentheses), you are making Ruby guess what you mean. If you always use `function(args)`, then Ruby KNOWS it is a function call with arguments. If you do not, then Ruby will have to guess what you mean.

Just as an example. Take `function 4 if true`. How would Ruby know what you mean here? Either it is `function((4 if true))`, or `function(4) if true`. Ruby has to "guess".

This was just an example, you have to combine this rule with rule number 2 below to understand the full picture:

2. You cannot put a control statement (if, while, unless, etc.) as a function argument, UNLESS YOU ENCLOSE IT IN PARENTHESES.

If you accept these two rules, 1 and 2 together, you will understand that this:

```
function (control_statement)
```

Will be interpreted as this:

```
function((control_statement))
```

And therefore the only form which is allowed, if you plan to use a control statement in an argument list, is this one:

```
Integer.sqrt((4 if true))
```

All other forms will confuse the interpreter, and are not allowed by the Ruby grammar.

Comment: Another way of interpreting `function (control statement)` would be `x = (contol statement); function x`. (I did have to bite my lip when writing "function" rather than "method".)

Comment: Good example..thanks. I think my Ruby terminology may be a bit rusty.

Comment: While your example is instructive, I think it would be more helpful to explain in particular the form `function  (4 if true)`, which is more akin to what the OP used.